# Finding the source of query in General Log

Tags: mysql

We use a similar query in our different code base modules and at times it gets difficult to check in General/Slow Query Log to find out the page where it got executed.

Is there anyway to pass some info to server while executing query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a comment in your queries:

```
$sql = "-- Called from myfile.php:
    SELECT * from table;";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

The comment will be considered part of the statement and logged along with the query itself.